An integer was expected
Sometimes I have received an error "An integer was expected." where not expected. Example in code:
$command = 'arping -c1 1.1.1.1'; // or many other command which can return something or can be empty.
$ssh->exec($command);

How to fix this error?
Must to return string, even if it is empty.
